# Assignment with no assignment operator compiles with no error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've found that if you have an assignment with no assignment operator in `Delphi 2007` then it compiles with no error as long as it is immediately after a `begin` in the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: word;
begin
  X := 0;
  begin
    X + 1;
  end;
end;
```

> 'X + 1' is not a valid statement in Delphi and yet it compiles.

It is the same for other operators. Take the begin away and you get the error :

> "[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(32): E2014 Statement expected

But expression of type `Integer` found:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: word;
begin
  X := 0;
  X + 1;
end;
```

Which is what I would expect. Does anyone have an explanation for this error?

Comment: It's a compiler bug. Not much point reporting it for such an old version.

Comment: It's  a compiler bug that has long since been fixed. As David said, posting a bug report for a 10-year old version of the compiler will accomplish nothing. (FWIW for future readers, Berlin says *[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(15): E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'Integer' found*.)